# escaping wildcards in LIKE SQL query with eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to prevent standard SQL underscore matching in this eloquent query:

```
$data = DB::table('items')
    ->distinct()
    ->select('item_name')
    ->where('item_name', 'LIKE', $term . '%')
    ->groupBy('item_name')
    ->take(15)
    ->get();
```

anyone knows how to do it with eloquent? Do I need to use whereRaw?
What's the syntax anyone?

Comment: What do you mean by `underscore matching`? Can you show some example?

Answer (score 2):

This helper method escapes all `LIKE` special characters, including the escape character itself.

```
/**
 * Escape special characters for a LIKE query.
 *
 * @param string $value
 * @param string $char
 *
 * @return string
 */
function escape_like(string $value, string $char = '\\')
{
    return str_replace(
        [$char, '%', '_'],
        [$char.$char, $char.'%', $char.'_'],
        $value
    );
}
```

So you would use it like: `$query->where('foo', 'like', '%'.escape_like('bar').'%')`

Comment: Why do you replace \\ with \\\\? and why don't you escape with one \ not two? for example \%

Comment: You have to write two backslashes otherwise you would be escaping the `'` character, but in reality it's just a single backslash.

Comment: `'` character doesn't need backslash escape character. actually everything in single quotation mark is already escaped. But it is needed in `"`.

Comment: If you want search directories like u:\App you need one more $char:

`return  str_replace(['\\', '%', '_'], ['\\\\\\', '\%', '\_'], $value);`

Answer (score -3):

Can use the following laravel query

```
$pdo = \DB::getPDO();
$escape_wild_card = "=_%"; 
$term = "something";
$term = $pdo->quote($term. $escape_wild_card);    /** Escaped & quoted input/term */  
$result = \DB::select(\DB::raw("SELECT * FROM items WHERE `item_name` LIKE $term ESCAPE '='"));
dd($result);
```

The corresponding raw sql query looks like:

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE `item_name` LIKE 'something=_%' ESCAPE '='
```

Comment: That does not escape underscore "_" though

Comment: Where you need to escape underscore Chriz ?

Comment: I have a search input in my page. If I input underscores it will show results from the DB based on any character and number of underscores. Example if I input ____ (4 underscores) it will show xxxx% items where xxxx is any combination of 4 chars matching in the DB + wildcard %. I want to avoid returning results when inputting underscores completely.

Comment: Then you can use the validation or conditions. When you find _ in the input you can return null directly, otherwise you can execute the query to return the proper result.

Comment: But in sql like query you can specify to escape characters. http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/like.php so I think you only have to escape _ in your whereRaw like condition.

Comment: This answer both fails to do what was asked (escaping % and _) while also introducing an SQL-injection vulnerability by not even escaping the value that is inserted into the SQL-query.

Comment: Yes @LarsNyström, You may be right... Data must be sanitized or input must be properly escaped or quoted before sending to the query as that is a common thing. Thanks for notifying...